# Reset Tkinter Window, Restore Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am hoping to create a button to completely reset a Tkinter window as if the program has been run from scratch. Here is my current way of doing this. However it is not working as hoped.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

    def do_something_():
         #*performing a function on widget*

    DoThing = Button(master, text='Do Something',command=do_something_).pack(pady=10)

    clearall = Button(master, text='reset', command=resetAll).pack(pady=10)

    def resetAll():

        master.destroy()

        master = Tk()

mainloop()
```

Is there any way to completely reset the window?

Comment: create function which create `Frame` with all widgets and put this frame in root window. Later you can destroy frame to remove all widgets and you can run the same function again to create new frame.

Comment: code `variable = Widget(...).pack(...)` asssigns `None` to `variable` because `pack/grid/place` returns `None`. And you don't have access to widget. If you need access then you have to do it in two steps `variable = Widget(...)` and `variable.pack(...)`. If you don't need access then you don't need variable - `Widget(...).pack(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a canvas (or frame) and then make the DoThing and clearall buttons have the canvas (or frame) as their master widget. You can then make the resetAll subroutine destroy the canvas (or frame). This will then destroy all of the canvas's child-widgets as well.

Note: I also fixed some syntax errors in your code (e.g. you defined the resetALL subroutine after referencing it.)

The code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def do_something_():
    print('do something') #I added this so that i can run the code with no errors
    #*performing a function on widget*

def resetAll():
    canvas.destroy() #destroys the canvas and therefore all of its child-widgets too


canvas = Canvas(master)
canvas.pack()
#creates the cnvas

DoThing = Button(canvas, text='Do Something',command=do_something_).pack(pady=10) 
#its master widget is now the canvas

clearall = Button(canvas, text='reset', command=resetAll).pack(pady=10)
#its master widget is now the canvas

master.mainloop()
```

I ran this code.

This was the GUI before i clicked the 'reset' button:

[image: gui1]

This was the GUI after i clicked the 'reset' button:

[image: gui2]

As you can see it worked. The canvas's child-widgets (the buttons) were destroyed because the canvas was destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

You can create function which create `Frame` and put widgets in this frame. And then you can put frame in window.

When you press button then you can `destroy()` this frame to remove all widgets and you can run the same function to create widgets again. Or you can run different function to create different frame with widgets - so you can replace content in window.

```
from tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def create_frame(master):
    print("create frame")

    frame = Frame(master)

    b = Button(frame, text='Do Something')
    b.pack(pady=10)

    clearall = Button(frame, text='reset', command=reset_all)
    clearall.pack(pady=10)

    return frame

def reset_all():
    global frame

    frame.destroy()
    frame = create_frame(master)
    #frame = create_different_frame(master)
    frame.pack()

# --- main ---


master = Tk()

frame = create_frame(master)
frame.pack()

mainloop()
```

---

BTW: if you do `var = Widget().pack()` then you assign `None` to `var` and you have no access to Widget - ie. you can't detroy it. You have to do it in two steps

```
var = Widget()
var.pack()
```

if you don't need access to widget then you don't need variable

```
Widget().pack()
```

And when you have access to all widgets then you can change settings (ie. clear text) in every widget instead of destroying all widgets.

Comment: I am adding widgets dynamically. Therefore when I run a function it adds widgets. However, I want to run the function multiple times and replace these widgets. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: if you want to remove all widgets at once then put empty `Frame` and add your widgets dynamically to frame. When you will not need widgets then destroy `Frame` and put new empty `Frame`. You can also keep all `var` on list and destroy only some elements from list. Widgets also have method `widget.children` to get list with all widgets which are inside widget. So `root.children` gives you all widget which you add dynamically in `root` and you can choose which one to remove or change settings.

Comment: Okay, I added the frame. However when destroying it, how do I add another frame that will use the same variables. Realistically I want to reset the frame completely. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you destroy frame will all widgets and then you create new frame and you add the same way as first one. And now you have place to create new widgets with new variables - the same way as you did in first frame. Why do you need old variables. or maybe you incorrectly describe problem ? And maybe you need only remove text in all widgets without removing them?